# Linked Lists Vs Arrays (Implemented?)

Tags: arrays, data-structures, linked-list

An array is a different data structure from a linked list right?
Or I can implement a linked list using an array?
I am kinda confused in this topic, would appreciate if you could help me.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> An array is a different data structure from a linked list right?

Yes, array and linked list are different data structures.

[**Linked list**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list):
*A Linked list is a linear collection of data elements, whose order is not given by their physical placement in memory. Instead, each element points to the next. It is a data structure consisting of a collection of nodes which together represent a sequence.*

Assume that you have node structure defined like this (using C language construct in the example):

```
struct Node 
{ 
    int data; 
    struct Node *next; 
};
```

Every node of linked list is having an integer and a pointer to its next node which is used to access the next member of the list (the last node next pointer set to `NULL`). The in-memory view would be something like this:

```
---------    ---------    ---------    ---------
| 1 |  -|--->| 2 |  -|--->| 3 |  -|--->| 4 |  -|--->NULL
---------    ---------    ---------    ---------
```

It provides flexibility in terms of insertion/deletion of elements in the list at any location, you just need to set/reset the next pointers of nodes. The disadvantage is that it requires **sequential traversal** to access its nodes.

[**Array**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_data_structure):
*An array data structure, or simply an array, is a data structure consisting of a collection of elements (values or variables), each identified by at least one array index or key.*

Assume that you have array of 5 integer (using C language construct in the example):

```
int arr[5] = {0}; // array of 5 integer initialized with 0
```

The in-memory view would be something like this:

```
  index   0   1   2   3   4
    arr ---------------------
        | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
        ---------------------
```

It's advantage is, you can **access any element of array directly through its index**. For e.g. if you want to access 3<sup>rd</sup> element, you can simply do `a[2]`. The disadvantage is that the insertion/deletion of elements in array at any location except at end of array is not straight forward. For that, you may have to shuffle the several elements of array.

> Or I can implement a linked list using an array?

Yes, you can. But you will not get any good advantage of doing so. Rather it will introduce unnecessary complexity in your code. Check [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10477754/implement-linked-list-using-array-advantages-disadvantages).

Comment: For some reason this topic has been kinda confusing for me but after reading your answer everything looks clear now! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Correct.  You can implement an array using a linked list, but it won't work quite as efficiently as an array as a normal C style array.  You could technically implement a linked list using an array, but it would at least inherit the array's relatively inflexible size.  It's not likely going to be the best implementation for whatever you're trying to accomplish.

Typically, a linked list is made up of nodes that have pointers to other nodes in the list, most or all of which will be in anonymously allocated memory blocks.  This gives you much more flexibility if you want to rearrange the elements in the list, including inserting elements into the middle of an existing list.

An array, on the other hand, has a set space.  Unless the language has done something to work around its limitations, it's not readily easy to grow it, although if it's dynamically allocated, you may be able to reallocate it to be bigger - but this could come at the cost of having to copy the whole thing to another memory region which has the space for all of that in a contiguous memory segment.

For what it's worth, I would bet that this question has been asked before on stack overflow, and somebody's given a better answer to it than I could, but finding it in all of the results of searching "Linked Lists Vs. Arrays" could be difficult.  That said, I'd guess you're at a point where many of those posts would also be educational as well.